# MIME type error with css file and load static showing in plain text - Django on PyCharm IDE

Tags: html, css, django, django-templates, pycharm

In my HTML template, when I pass it to debug mode, gets the following errors:

1. Refused to apply style from its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.;

[MIME Error]== Refused to apply style from 'http://localhost:63342/YouTrade1/templates/YouTrade1/%7B%%20static%20'StyleS.Creators.css'%20%%7D' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not a supported stylesheet MIME type, and strict MIME checking is enabled.

2. '{% load static %}' shows in plain text;

`Pics and css files are in YouTrade1/static/YouTrade1 Template is in YouTrade1/templates/YouTrade1`

I tried several solutions for the documentation of my static files and none seem to work.
All documentation according to Django best practices.

I don't manage to understand whether there's something wrong with either my django project setup (which looks fine), my testing environment (I click debug/run on pyCharm IDE and they said it's all fine on their side) or my HTML script.

SETTINGS

```
"""
Django settings for YouTrade1 project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.2.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from pathlib import Path
import os

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = xxx

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []

# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware',

]

ROOT_URLCONF = 'YouTrade1.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'YouTrade1', 'templates/YouTrade1/YT_AboutUs.html',
                             'templates/YouTrade1/YT_Creators.html', 'templates/YouTrade1/YT_Investors.html'),

        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'YouTrade1.wsgi.application'

# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': BASE_DIR / 'db.sqlite3',
    }
}

# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator',
    },
    {
        'NAME': 'django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator',
    },
]

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True

# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates/YouTrade1/static/YouTrade1'),]

WHITENOISE_MIMETYPES = {
    '.css': 'text/css',
}

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = 'django.db.models.BigAutoField'
```

URLS

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path
from django.conf.urls.static import static
from django.conf import settings
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns
from .views import home1



urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('YouTrade1\YT_Creators.html', home1, name='home1'),]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

VIEWS

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.template import loader
from django.shortcuts import render

def home1(request):
    context = {"YT_Creators": "home1"}
    return render(request, "YT_Creators.html", context)
```

HTML Page

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

{% load static %}

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8"/>
    <title>Creators</title>

</head>
<body>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'StyleS.Creators.css' %} ">

</body>
</html>
```

CSS File

```
body {
    background-image: url(BeYou.jpg);
}
```

Comment: Do not post pictures of code.

Comment: Why? I couldn't put it on the question because it gave me an error

Comment: You should read and understand the rules and guidelines for questions before posting. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask  https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors

Comment: Can you post settings.py? And are you trying to use whitenose to host static files?

Comment: Django normally with default, doesn't host static files or media files. You need to add urls to project urls.py for static and media files.

Comment: If you have code, post them like ```code```. With three "`" at both ends of code. Only otherwise post images. Even then embed images. Not links. Just informing. .

Comment: Great, thanks I will. Anyways yes I will post settings.py rn!

Comment: Anyways I tried with whitenose too, but it doesn't seem to work properly even in that case. Contacting the PyCharm IDE support they suggested is likely an HTML or CSS error, but I still didn't find a different way of properly referencing static images that would then display once I run debug, so probably there is something I get wrong when I do run the debug? For example, in the HTML page that loads, I cannot find the CSS file.